# Ellipsis with sideways curly bracket

Tags: amsmath, braces, ellipsis

I'm writing a math proof and need to expand an exponentiation into *n* multiplications.  I would like to have something like:

*A x A x A x A ........... A x A x A*

with a largy curly bracket open upwards around the whole thing saying "n times"  Is there some way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I don't really understand what your intended output is. Maybe you can draw a sketch, or make a screenshot from a book or paper where this is done, and add this to your question? Also, for potential answerers to try things out it would be helpful if you would provide the code for a small example document that contains this expression (but without the brackets etc.), that makes it easier to provide an answer and also it would increase the probability that the solution is actually something that you can use in your real document.

Comment: @Marijn - I think the OP is looking for the `\overbrace` macro...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \underbrace{A \times A \times A \times \dots \times A}_{n \text{ times}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you're looking to use the `\overbrace{...}^{...}` macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for '\overbrace' macro
\begin{document}
\[
\overbrace{A\times A\times\dots\times A\times A}^{\text{$n$ times}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

For later, and if you have a lot of them, `lmake` package does nice patterns.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lmake}
\begin{document}
\Large

\[ \lmake[A_{\i}, \!] \]

\[ \lmake[A_{\i}, \,] \]

\[ \lmake[{A_{\i}}, \times] \]

\[ \lmake[\left(\frac{\i}{\i+1}\right),\!]\]

\end{document}
```

[image: example]